# procedure prematurely skipped in conditional feedback #psychopy

Tags: branch, conditional-statements, feedback, psychopy

i exploited conditional branching in the builder with inline code to provide feedback after incorrect trials only by setting nRep of the feedback loop to 1 only after these trials. it works well, however, after a while the preceding procedure (trial -> feedback) exits without any response prior the duration time of my items ended ..

is there a better way to provide conditional feedback and/or am i missing some thought?

Answer (score 1):

We will probably need some more detail of what you have actually done to answer this.

At a guess, make sure your Keyboard component does not have a set duration and is set to "Force end of routine" (i.e. its "Stop (duration)" field should be empty). That way, the preceding trial should last indefinitely, until a key press is received.